# How to create common folder for css and js files in Django?

Tags: python, django

setting before any change.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

here I want to create one static files folder rather than assigning them to each every app by creating there name as directory and then I have to assign. So I want one common folder for all JS and Css which can be reflected in each and every template rather than defining all of them at different places.

Answer (score 2):

firstly make below changes in your settings.py file :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "allfiles"),
]
```

Remember that allfiles is also folder in your project root.
After that in your template load static files as given below:
inside template.py:

```
{% load static %}
<html><script src="{% static 'index.js' %}"></html>
<--this file is in your common file you can replace it with any JS or CSS-->
```